# SSIS convert string to datetime/date

Tags: ssis

Trying to import data into SQL table from Excel.
One of the columns "RptDt" on Excel file is datetime but 
sometime it has some string/varchar values "Null" (not Null). 
OleDestination has column "RptDt" with data type "Dt_date".

I get an error because SSIS takes this "Null" as string when trying to transfer the data to sql.

I'm trying to use derived column but i'm not sure if i have right expression to satisfy dates and string value.

```
 ISNULL([RptDt] ? (DT_WSTR, 50)("Null") :NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE) [RptDt]
```

Sample column value on RptDt.

```
08/09/2013

10/09/2013 
Null
NULL
```

All i'm trying to do is, If column value is string then pass Null value 
if not pass date.

Comment: Any thoughts, Please!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can insert `NULL` in your table use this derived column code:

```
 ISNULL([RptDt]) || [RptDt]=="Null" ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE)[RptDt]
```